# error when I translate installed modules in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

When i want to translate installed modules in prestashop it show me the following error

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/themes/leoshoes/modules/blockadvertising/fr.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /controllers/admin/AdminTranslationsController.php on line 654
```

i use prestashop 1.5.0.17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing the appropriate permissions on the file/folder.
- Check that the directory /themes/leoshoes/modules/blockadvertising/ exists and set the permissions to 777 (read, write, execute).
- If the file /themes/leoshoes/modules/blockadvertising/fr.php exists set the permissions to 777. If you cannot change the permissions, maybe you can try removing the file.